# Javascript on page load without appending to body

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, jumi

I'm trying to show an image using a Jumi module in Joomla.  Currently, the script is calling to append to the body tag but this places the image at the bottom of my template.  I need to be able to run my script without appending to the body but can't just call the function since my script uses an if else statement to determine what to do.  I'm very new to JS but is there a way to append to a paragraph tag or a div?

[Link Here to Website](http://askc.org/galacticos/index.php)

```html
<script>
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt;
    
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
    var month = new Date().getMonth();
  var time = new Date().getHours();
  var day = new Date().getDay();

if (month > "3" && month < "10" && day == "6" && time > "19" && time <= "22") {
show_image("http://bizeebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/open-sign.jpg",500,450, "Powell is OPEN");
}
else { show_image("http://get.whotrades.com/u3/photoBB09/20171363290-0/blogpost.jpeg",500,450, "Powell is CLOSED");}
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your requirement.

Comment: Have you scrolled down all the way on your page? (the image is there)

Comment: Yes I've scrolled down, hence the problem.  I want to load the image where I put the code, which is just prior to the twitter feed on the middle of the page.  To do this, I need to get rid of the document.body.appendChild(img) code, but I don't know what to replace it with so that I can place the result of the code where I want on the page.

Comment: Select the target element using `DOM-api` for eg. `document.getElementById` and then append the element in it..

Comment: Rayon, I was trying to do something like this but had no luck.  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

```
<div id='my-element'></div>
```

...

```
document.getElementById("my-element").appendChild(img);
```

This will append your `img` to the element whose id you provide.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild